# Adding values to a dictionary via inline initialization of its container

Tags: c#, dictionary, initialization

I have the following `City` class. Each city object contains a dictionary which keys are language tags (let's say: "EN", "DE", "FR"...) and which values are the city names in the corresponding languages (ex: Rome / Rom etc.).

```
public class City:
{
  private IDictionary<string, string> localizedNames = new Dictionary<string, string>(0);
  public virtual IDictionary<string, string> Names
  {
    get { return localizedNames ; }
    set { localizedNames = value; }
  }
}
```

Most of the cities have the same names whatever the language so the `City` constructor does actually creates the English mapping:

```
  public City(string cityName)
  {
    this.LocalizedNames.Add("EN", cityName);
  }
```

**Here comes the question**: is there a way to add the other values via inline initialization?

I tried different variations of the following without semantic success (does not compile):

```
AllCities.Add(new City("Rome") { Names["DE"] = "Rom" };
```

I also tried creating a new Dictionary, but this obviously overwrites the "EN" parameter:

```
AllCities.Add(new City("Rome") { Names = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "DE", "Rom" } } };
```

Anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
AllCities.Add(new City("Rome") { Names = { { "DE", "Rom" }, { "...", "..." } } });
```

This is using initializer syntax to invoke the .Add method.

Comment: This will overwrite the value added in the constructor, just as the last code block provided by the asker will.

Comment: No it won't. It will add to the existing dictionary. It will not create a new one.

Comment: ... You got me, I didn't try it. Give me a second. If you're right I will humbly apologise.

Comment: `orz` My humble apologies. This does exactly what you said. -1 => +1.

Comment: (And that's some weird initializer synax there. You learn something new every day.)

Comment: Damn, I'm pretty sure that't the first thing I tried... works indeed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should have given an example with at least two items in your dictionary :)

Answer (score 71):

this is actual inline intialization:

```
private IDictionary<string, string> localizedNames = new Dictionary<string, string>{
    {"key1","value1"},
    {"key2","value2"}
};
```

**Update:**
If you are using C# 6.0 or later, key value based syntax is also supported:

```
IDictionary<string, string> localizedNames = new Dictionary<string,string>
{
    ["key1"] = "value1",
    ["key2"] = "value2",
    ["key3"] = "value3"
};
```

Answer (score 7):

There's a better approach to this than using [anonymous objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42729249/13574233):

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new()
{
    ["key1"] = "value1",
    ["key2"] = "value2",
    ["key3"] = "value"
};
```

---

**EDIT: As to OPs request for an explanation**

From [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers):

```cs
var numbers = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    [7] = "seven",
    [9] = "nine",
    [13] = "thirteen"
};
```

> The preceding sample generates code that calls the [Item[TKey]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_Item__0_) to set the values. Before C# 6, you could initialize dictionaries and other associative containers using the following syntax. Notice that instead of indexer syntax, with parentheses and an assignment, it uses an object with multiple values:

```cs
var moreNumbers = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {19, "nineteen" },
    {23, "twenty-three" },
    {42, "forty-two" }
};
```

> This initializer example calls [Add(TKey, TValue)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.add#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_Add__0__1_) to add the three items into the dictionary. These two different ways to initialize associative collections have slightly different behaviour because of the method calls the compiler generates. Both variants work with the `Dictionary` class. Other types may only support one or the other based on their public API.

---

For me, it's just a readability thing. I think it's way easier to read and understand what's done because you can also retrieve the values with the `[]` brackets. I don't know anything about performance though but I guess the first way would also be the better option too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Given that the question is from 2012, I would add that the indexer way you suggest was introduced in C#6.0. And could you explain why you think it is better?

Comment: @TimothéeBourguignon I added the explanation. Hope this helps.